# Search Scope Definition for [(a OR b) AND (c OR d)]

Tags: search, crawl-rules

Using SP2010 I would like to define a search scope where documents are located in two locations. The results should only include two specific file types. What I want is

(Folder = "a" OR Folder = "b") AND (FileExtension = "c" OR FileExtension = "d")

Can I do this only with the **Include** and **Require** rules?

To be more precise: what I am currently trying is 4 rules:
1. Include FileExtension = "c" 
2. Include FileExtension = "d" 
3. Require Folder = "a" 
4. Require Folder = "b"
-> fails, because a file cannot be in two folders at the same time. In other words, what SharePoint does is (c OR d) AND a AND b.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with the KeyWordQuery Syntax:

Have a look at the follwing links for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872310.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509

So your query should be something like:

```
(folder:a OR folder:b) AND (filetype:c OR filetype:d)
```

I am not sure about the exact name of the "folder" property. You will have to look it up in the managed properties for search.

Comment: I am not building a query. I would like to define a search scope, i.e. the set of potential query results.